# Append number of days since the date in the line to each line in the file using Bash

Tags: bash, date

I have a file that consists of the following...

```
false|aaa|user|aaa001|2014-12-11|
false|bbb|user|bbb||
false|ccc|user|ccc|2021-10-19|
false|ddd|user|ddd|2018-11-16|
false|eee|user|eee|2020-06-02|
```

I want to use the date in the 5th column to calculate the number of days from the current date and append it to each line in the file.

The end result would be a file that looks like the following, assuming the current date is 1/13/2022...

```
false|aaa|user|aaa001|2014-12-11|2590
false|bbb|user|bbb||
false|ccc|user|ccc|2021-10-19|86
false|ddd|user|ddd|2018-11-16|1154
false|eee|user|eee|2020-06-02|590
```

Some lines in the file will not contain a date value (which is expected).  I need a solution for a Bash script on Linux.

I am able to submit a command using echo for a single line and then calculate the number of days from the current date by using cut on the 5th field (see below)...

```
echo "false|aaa|user|aaa001|2014-12-11" | echo $(( ($(date --date=date +"%Y-%m-%d" +%s) - $(date --date=cut -d'|' -f5 +%s) )/(60*60*24) )) 
2590
```

I don't know how to do this one line at a time, capture the 'number of days' value and then append it to each line in the file.

Comment: What have you tried? What is your question? We can help if you have a specific coding part you're stuck on, like date manipulation or column-based text processing, but we can't do much with just a list of requirements.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question with that information? Code is hard to read in comments, and comments can be deleted at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using

- `paste` to append the outputs
- `sed` to arrange the empty lines and
- `awk` to calculate the desired days.

This works with **GNU** `date`. **BSD** `date` has to use something like `date -jf x +%s`.

EDIT: Updated the date to compare with to current day.

```
% current=$(date +%m/%d/%Y)
% paste -d"\0" file <(cut -d"|" -f5 file |
         sed 's/^$/#/' |
         xargs -Ix date -d x +%s 2>&1 |
         awk -v cur="$(date -d "$current" +%s)" '/invalid/{print 0; next} 
           {print int((cur-$1)/3600/24)}')
false|aaa|user|aaa001|2014-12-11|2590
false|bbb|user|bbb||0
false|ccc|user|ccc|2021-10-19|86
false|ddd|user|ddd|2018-11-16|1154
false|eee|user|eee|2020-06-02|590
```

Also `date` returns `date: invalid date ‘#’` in the empty case. If any other implementation behaves differently the awk regex has to be adjusted accordingly.

##### Data

```
% cat file
false|aaa|user|aaa001|2014-12-11|
false|bbb|user|bbb||
false|ccc|user|ccc|2021-10-19|
false|ddd|user|ddd|2018-11-16|
false|eee|user|eee|2020-06-02|
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering questions which exhibit no effort; we don't want to encourage them.

Comment: @tripleee Agreed, but the edit did show at least a direction which I thought was adequate for now.

Comment: @AndreWildberg Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  This solution works.  The only change I made was in the awk command so the current date isn't hard-coded - I'm getting the current date.